# Spring boot - Default properties file not being read when using profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot 2 application with 2 property files:

- application.properties
- application-dev.properties

When I run the application in IntellijIdea using the dev profile, Spring reads both the profile specific file and the default file.

Once I build an executable jar file, I created a new application-prod.properties outside of the jar, with production environment properties and execute the application with `--spring.profiles.active=prod` expecting it to read this file AND the default `application.properties`, but it is only reading the file outside the jar (application-prod.properties).

Should Spring Boot read both files or am I expecting something that it does not do by default?

If it should, what can I be missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of the JAR"?

Comment: how are you telling that it reads from default an dev profile? show something to us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Michael, Spring boot supports [property hierarchies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

I tried this and it works as expected, you can find a reference project in [here](https://github.com/jlmayorga/springboot-propertysource-test)

A few things that I can think about:

- Extract the contents of your jar file and confirm that the file named application.properties is bundled in there.
- You may be overwriting the spring.config.location property and using filenames instead of directories

From [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

> If you have specified any files in spring.config.location, profile-specific variants of those files are not considered. Use directories in spring.config.location if you want to also use profile-specific properties.

- If you override the default spring.config.location then the application may not be able to find the default application.properties file.

Comment: You nailed it. I was using  spring.config.location to change the location of the external properties file. I changed it to spring.config.additional-location and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

By default, application.properties will be used to run the Spring Boot application. While running the JAR file, you need to specify the spring active profile. only one file will be read

Comment: That is not true. Spring supports property hierarchies. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html